# Copying from an Observable to an Observer

Tags: rxjs

I would like to copy the contents of an `Observable` into an `Observer`.

Is there a succinct way of achieving this without resorting to `subscribe()` and manually pumping events from the `Observable` to the `Observer`? i.e.

```
    var observer = new Subject();
    var observable = new Subject();

    observable.subscribe(i => observer.next(i), e => observer.error(e), () => observer.complete())
```

NOTE: Above code example is in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a point in doing so. Are you planning to merge multiple observers into one? there is an operator for that: [`Observable.merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge).

If you can't use merge, the shortest way to do so is to use the [right version of subscribe](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe):

```
var observer = new Subject();
var observable = new Subject();

observable.subscribe(observer);
```

**EDIT**

Assume your initialization code looks something like the following:

```
function initStream() {
  var subject = new Subject();
  loadConfigurationCallback(config => {
    const observable = createStreamBasedOnConfig(config);
    observable.subscribe(subject);
  });
  return subject;
}
```

In this case you can simplify more if you make the `loadConfiguration` itself returning an observable:

```
function initStream() {
  return loadConfigurationObservable().flatMap(createStreamBasedOnConfig);
}
```

Comment: I have a method where I need to return an Observable<> immediately, but I can't start populating it until some other async operations take place (loading configuration, etc).

Comment: @jwa I see, so you met the hard part of rx. Another solution would be to create an observable of the result of those asynchronous operations initially, and flatMap the new resulting observables from it.

Comment: If I understand your proposal correctly, this means I'd get the result of the async operations in my final Observable too? Thus I'd then have to add a filter, given I don't want those in my final Observable stream?

Comment: Added an example to the answer, maybe that makes clearer what I mean.